# RegExp: want to find all links that do not end in ".html"

Tags: regex, notepad++, negative-lookbehind, regex-lookarounds

I'm a relative novice to regular expressions (although I've used them many times successfully).
I want to find all links in a document that do not end in ".html"
The regular expression I came up with is:

```
href=\"([^"]*)(?<!html)\"
```

In Notepad++, my editor, `href=\"([^"]*)\"` finds all the links (both those that end in "html" and those that do not).
Why doesn't negative lookbehind work?

I've also tried lookahead:

```
href=\"[^"]*(?!html\")
```

but that didn't work either.

Can anybody help?

Cheers, grovel

Comment: I think Notepad++ just does not support look-behind assertions.

Comment: It is so ugly to try to get regex working with Notepad++. I give up, there are so many annoying restrictions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That regular expression would work fine, if you were using PERL or PCRE (e.g. preg_match in PHP). However, lookahead and lookbehind assertions are not supported by most, especially the more simple, regular expression engines, like one that is used by the Notepad++. Only the most basic syntax such as quantifiers, subpatterns and characters classes are supported by almost all regular expression engines.

You can find the documentation for the notepad++ regular expression engine at: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

Comment: The documentation is confusing, because it has a section on lookarounds, which seems to indicate they are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Notepad++ using SciTE regular expression engine and it does not support look around expressions.

For more info take a look here http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html

---

Original Answer

<s>`^.*(?<!\.html)$`</s>

Answer (score 1):

You can make a regexp that does it, but it would probably be too complex:

```
href=\"((([^"]*)([^h"][^"][^"][^"]|[^t"][^"][^"]|[^m"][^"]|[^l]))|([^"]|)([^"]|)([^"]|))\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much.

In the end the regular expression did indeed not work.

I simply used a workaround, and replaced all links with themselves+".html", then replaced all occurences of ".html.html" with ".html".

So I replaced `href=\"([^"]*)\"` with `href="\1.html"` and then `.html.html` with `.html`

Thanks anyway, grovel

Answer (score 0):

Note that Notepad++ (now?) supports [assertions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions#Assertions) like this.  (I have Notepad++ 6.3, dated Feb 3 2012.)

I believe the [Regular Expressions documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions#Assertions) implies that both replace-variants use the same PCRE-dialect:

- standard: `Search | Replace` (default shortcut `Ctrl H`)
- plugin: `TextFX | TextFX Quick | Find/Replace` (default shortcut `Ctrl R`)